# PerformanceCounter PhysicalDisk % Disk Time wrong value

Tags: c#, performancecounter

```
private static PerformanceCounter PC18 = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Disk Time", "_Total");
```

Calling the Counter using:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"PC18.NextValue()");
}
```

This Timer, is set to 1 second intervals.

I am getting values that have no corresponding Disk Usage %, values like 130.02 and so on are being displayed.

This is the only PerformanceCounter I can find that does Disk Usage. Why am I getting the wrong values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha, the instanceName, '_total' is not the figure on of disk, its all disks.

So, an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172778/1183804) fixed my problem:

```
PC18 = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Disk Time", "0 C:");
```

Where: '0 C:' is the Instance Name of my physical disk C:

Thanks to 'Henk Holterman', all though the answer was not entirely clear, it was enough to make towards the final answer. Thanks!

```
PerformanceCounterCategory Category = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("PhysicalDisk");
string[] InstanceNames = Category.GetInstanceNames();

foreach (string Name in InstanceNames)
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Name + Environment.NewLine);
```

That will give you the Instance Names you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perfmon.exe to get exact def's (Hans Passant; Mar 2011).

```
PerformanceCounter PcHdd = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Idle Time", "_Total");

// then inside a loop use  ...
var DiskUsage = 100 - PcHdd.NextValue();
```

NB: "_Total" does not work with "% Disk Time". Still a relevant question in 2024.

Cheers.